# Reading XML from resource

Tags: xml, wpf

I am trying to read an XML from a resource but it is return an error.  Here is my code;

```
string s = Properties.Resources.myXMLFile;
XDocument x = XDocument.Load(s);
```

The error message is as follows;

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.
```

Stepping through the code I can see the XML file in the string `s`.  Opening the file both in VS and other XML parsers the file does not give any errors.  Why is this error occurring?

Comment: What kind of resource is it? Embedded, embedded resource, file in application folder, ...? Have you tried using a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XDocument.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects string containing path to an XML file as argument. If you have the XML content as string, you should use [`XDocument.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead :

```
string s = Properties.Resources.myXMLFile;
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(s);
```